# Convert list with nested lists of different lengths and empty elements into dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to convert the following list into a dataframe.

```
test <- list(list("a",c("b","c","d"),character(0)),list("j",c("r","s"),character(0)),list("h",character(0),"i"))
```

I tried the following:

```
df.test <- do.call(rbind,Map(data.frame, V1=sapply(test, "[[", 1),V2=sapply(test, "[[", 2),V3=sapply(test, "[[", 3)))
```

But this doesn't work with nested lists containing character(0). A satisfactory output looks something like this:

```
     V1  V2  V3
  1  a   b   NA
  2  a   c   NA
  3  a   d   NA
  4  j   r   NA
  5  j   s   NA
  6  h   NA  i
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
  map_df(~.x %>% 
           map(~if(length(.)) . else NA) %>% 
           do.call(what = cbind) %>% 
           as_tibble)
```

Gives

```
  V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     NA   
2 a     c     NA   
3 a     d     NA   
4 j     r     NA   
5 j     s     NA   
6 h     NA    i
```